# Data Binding not passing correctly to controller function parameter inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I am building a menu to allow users to change CSS on my webapp. My js method takes a string and then adds it into a URI for a bootswatch CDN. The code works when I hardcode a string. When I use the databound variable, it gets interesting. In developer tools I see the HTML shows there is the databound string as it should be. When I go to see which URI the browser is trying to GET, it is literally adding {{style}} to the URI. I'm quite new to all this so please forgive any huge flaws. I am open to any and all suggestions.

Here's my opening html tag:

```
<html data-ng-app="app" lang="en" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    // default on load for now
    $scope.stylePath = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    $scope.styles = ['slate', 'Cyborg', "Darkly", "journal", "Yeti"];
    $scope.setStyle = function(styleName) {
        $scope.stylePath = '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/' + styleName + '/bootstrap.min.css';
    };
    $scope.changePath = function() {
        $scope.stylePath='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/slate/bootstrap.min.css';
    };
});
```

As you can see, in my array, I have tried different types of quotes as well as lowercase and uppercase. (the word has to be lowercase) It is also worth noting that changePath() works fine. setStyle() hasn't ever worked when I've tried passing it a data bound value. Passing it a string literal has no problems.

Here's the code in question:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a id="ThemeDropdown" class="btn btn-default" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Choose a theme">Themes <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ThemeDropdown">
        <li role="presentation" data-ng-repeat="style in styles">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#/settings" ng-click="setStyle('{{style}}')">{{ style }}</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#/settings" ng-click="changePath()">hardcode slate</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#/settings" ng-click="setStyle('darkly')">hardcode darkly</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

BTW, not putting quotes around the databinding at the setStyle() call brings me a parse error.

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$parse/syntax?p0=style&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=12&p3=setStyle(%7B%7Bstyle%7D%7D)&p4=style%7D%7D)
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:6:450
at cb.throwError (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:168:341)
at cb.consume (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:169:266)
at cb.object (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:177:45)
at cb.primary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:167:478)
at cb.unary (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:174:160)
at cb.multiplicative (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:173:402)
at cb.additive (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:173:262)
at cb.relational (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js:173:126) <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#/settings" ng-click="setStyle({{style}})">
angular.js:10023
```

Is it possible to do what I'm doing? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#/settings" ng-click="setStyle('{{style}}')">{{ style }}</a>
```

should be

```
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#/settings" ng-click="setStyle(style)">{{ style }}</a>
```

No need to use any binding inside the call.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!!! (now all I need to do is figure out how to change it to lowercase...)